# set height and width to fixed but content to auto

Tags: css, reactjs, styling

I am creating cards widgets in react using css:

The second one has the subvalue and date on the right and there is space on the left. I set `height` and `width` to `auto` because I want the card to be responsive and take the width and height of the elements inside because I'm not always gonna have these amount of values.

How can I implement this behavior but also have spacing like this:

card.js:

```
<div className={styles.card}>
    <div className={styles.title}>
    {title}
    </div>
    <div className={styles.value}>
    {value}
    </div>
    <div className="unit">
    {unit}
    </div>
    <div className={styles.subValue}>
    {subValue}
    </div>
    <div className={styles.date}>
    {date}
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.card{
    border: 1px solid #57c0e8;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    object-fit: contain;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.title {
    color:grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
}

.value{
    font-size: 32px;
    /* margin-top: 6px; */
    text-align: center;
}

.subValue {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: block;
    min-height:25px;
}


.date {
    color:lightslategrey;
    text-align: right;
    /* display:flex;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 11px; */
}
```

I'm not that good with css that's why I need help please

Comment: It would be ideal if you could convert your JSX markup into plain HTML (Just use some dummy data) and turn it into a snippet so people can see the issue first hand. This looks like you should be able to just have the date at 100% width and use text alignment to right align it.

Comment: I guess you just need more space for all the cards. Increase the parent's width.